# Mock the watch funtion from React Hook Form in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, storybook

I have a form with fields that are shown based on a value pulled from the watch function of useFormContext in React Hook Form. It works fine within the form as a whole but I have a Storybook for each section of the form. When I log the watched value in Storybook it comes up as `undefined` despite a default being set. Do you have to mock the watch? I have also tried pulling setValue out of the context within Storybook and setting it before returning the component but it did not work either.

Code of the component:

```html
export const FormFields = () => {
    const {
        fields,
        controlled,
        clearErrors,
        formState: { errors },
        setValue,
        setError,
        watch,
    } = useFormContext();

    const [calculationType] = watch([
        'calculationType',
    ]);

    const isGrowth = calculationType === 'Growth'
    

    return (
        <div>
            {isGrowth
                ? controlled(
                        ({ value }) => (
                            <div
                            />
                        ),
                        fields.field1,
                  )
                : null}
            {isGrowth
                ? controlled(
                        (props) => (
                            <div
                            />
                        ),
                        {
                            ...fields.field2
                        },
                  )
                : null}
            
        </div>
    );
};
```

Code from Storybook:

```html
const mockFormValues = [
{
    name: 'calculationType',
    label: 'label',
    defaultValue: 'Growth',
},
{
    name: 'field1',
    label: 'field1',
    defaultValue: 1,
},
{
    name: 'field2',
    label: 'field2',
    defaultValue: 10,
}]

const Template = (args) => {
    const form = useForm<MyFormFields>(mockFormValues);

    return (
        <FormProvider {...form}>
            <EquityValuesFormFields {...args} />
        </FormProvider>
    );
};

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {};
```